Answer my own very specific question, or delete it
Re: 3-way switch without proper travelers
I asked the above question earlier today and was asked to draw a diagram (a very useful request). In the process of verifying everything for the diagram, I went back up into the attic, and found it just as easy to add travelers and remove the superfluous cable while I was up there. Now the 3-way switch works properly. Is this question so specific to the bizarre wiring I discovered that I should just delete it? Or should I answer it myself. The text description was difficult to follow, which, it seems, is what led to downvotes, this tells me the community doesn't think this is a quality question and suggests I should delete it, but I thought I'd check in on meta first.

Please feel free to answer it yourself, and checkmark your own answer. If you add info showing how you fixed it, perhaps with an edited sketch in your answer showing the fix, it will help someone in the future.
